# Understanding the reasons for a Schengen visa refusal

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, visa-refusals

I'm 17 years old, Sudanese, and I live in the UAE. I registered for a German course in Munich, and I got an invitation from a family friend who is German and applied for a tourist visa. It got refused; the reasons:

> You have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence, for the duration of the intended stay or for the return to the country of origin or residence, or for the transit to a third country into which you are certain to be admitted, or you are not in a position to acquire such means lawfully.
>   [and]
>   The information submitted regarding justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.

I really don't understand; what do they mean? How can I appeal this?

Comment: Which documents did you submit with your application?

Comment: Re-apply, this time present a bank statement with a bigger amount, and do not mention study, just say you are going for tourism, also bring a copy of your father's job certificate since he is your supporter still (you are 17). and حظ سعيد

Comment: Regarding "reliability". Here in the UK, there was an outcry recently about disreputable colleges that enrol so-called students that don't actually do any studies, just use the course as a false reason on a visa. I don't know if the same concern is widespread in Germany, but it's at least possible that the provider of your course isn't considered trustworthy by the immigration authorities. If so it's not personal, it's about the reputation of the school and not your reputation.

Comment: @SteveJessop I recall hearing about a similar immigration scam in the US a few years ago.  I'd be surprised if it's not happening in other places too.

Comment: You're applying for a *tourist* visa but you state *study* as reason. Not sure if that combination is allowed.

Comment: @CodesInChaos because the course is just 4 weeks they told me it's too short so I have to apply for a tourist visa

Comment: @CodesInChaos It's perfectly fine, a Schengen visa is not a tourist visa at all, it's a short-stay visa. There are some examples about that in the Schengen [Handbook](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf)

Comment: Note: see also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The procedure to appeal should be explained in the refusal notification. Basically, it seems you should complain in writing, explaining why you think you do qualify for a visa. [There is a page about that](http://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/DE/Infoservice/FAQ/VisumFuerD/10-Ablehnung.html?nn=350374) (in German) on the website of the German Foreign Ministry but it's not very detailed.

> You have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence, for the duration of the intended stay or for the return to the country of origin or residence, or for the transit to a third country into which you are certain to be admitted, or you are not in a position to acquire such means lawfully.

You should have a certain amount of money for each day you plan to spend in the Schengen area (even if you are staying with a friend) and also enough money to return to the UAE. You should therefore provide evidence of that (e.g. bank account statement). Having a return ticket would also satisfy the “return to the country of origin or residence”.

> The information submitted regarding justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.

This one will be tougher to satisfy. It suggests the consular officer does not believe you are coming to Germany for a course and suspects you might try to stay illegally at the end of the stay. Perhaps they don't consider the school to be serious or do not believe your family friend can really host you. Did you submit some confirmation of your registration for the course?

It's a slightly different issue but showing you have reasons to come back to the UAE (say a school registration, a job, a house, a family) could also help alleviate concerns. Unfortunately, those decisions are sometimes a bit arbitrary and it's not always possible to do something about it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you tell my how to prove that I have enough money for each day I'm planning to stay? because I already submitted a bank statement and it had a big amount of money

Comment: For the second reason yes I did submit a confirmation of my registration for the course. If there are any other things I can do so  I can get my visa please tell me because I really want to go. Thank you

Comment: Course registration may not be enough if, for whatever reason, the consular officer suspects you're not going to Germany to really study. I saw many foreigners (although it was in France) entering university, especially public universities with cheap tuition fee, to extend their stay. It is particularly true if the university has a dropping policy where you get back a substantial amount of your tuition fee, with a low risk of student visa cancellation. 

You may raise your chances if you have a way to justify why you want to study in Germany and not in UAE.

Comment: @Relaxed in the visa refusal paper is says I can appeal within one month, but I don't know how to appeal, should I just send them the extra documents or to write a letter or what? Or it's better to re- apply?

Comment: @Taladris That's possible although the reasons for taking a German course in Germany seem pretty obvious and what you describe is mostly relevant for one-year student visas, not Schengen visas.

Comment: @Abdullah Yes, sending a letter seems like a good idea, adding some extra documents too if you have something relevant to offer.

Comment: Have your friend given you a "verpflichtungserklärung" (formal obligation letter), which you submitted with the application? You also need to show bank statements with sufficient funds.

Comment: @Anirudh Yes, I submitted a bank statement with big amount of money and I did submit the "Verpflichtungserklärung" i got it from a family friend who is German.