# French Schengen visa refused in India - what to do?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, visa-refusals

I am an Indian national working in Kuwait with residency here. I wanted to take my family on a euro trip this may. The family included my wife and daughter (who live with me) and my parents-in-law who live in India.

We made an itinerary with 3 countries, first port of entry France, however number of days in Italy, hence applied for Schengen visa at the Italian embassy both in Kuwait (for us) and in India ( for our parents-in-law). I am the sponsor for all.

Our parents-in-law got their visa, however, our visa in Kuwait was refused as I had maintained a low bank balance in my account. 
Hence, the five of us did not travel.

Now, we rescheduled the trip to September (this month).This time our itinerary was a little longer (14 days as against the previous 9 days), we added a couple more days in France and added another country.So , this time we applied for Schengen visa at the French embassy in Kuwait and India.
However, we did not apply in parallel, waited for our visa result to apply for our parents-in-law.

We received our visa in Kuwait and submitted to them in India. However, their visa got refused to state "information provided for purpose and conditions of the trip not reliable ".

We submitted all documentation inc. flight return tickets, accommodations, inter-country train tickets, sponsors bank statements, salary certificate, leave certificate, our visa etc.....we also added bank statements, FD's and share papers of the father-in-law.

I want to reapply this week and try one last time.
I have expanded my covering letter incl. the following information:

1. why they did not travel last may (inc. our refusal letter as proof)
2. why we have applied at the different embassy(explained the change in itinerary)
3. attached some local tours we have booked in each country to show that we mean to respect our itinerary.
4. added property papers of own house of father-in-law to ensure that he will be returning back.

What else can I do? What went wrong?

Comment: Could you post the exact text of the refusal? It looks like you haven't used the exact words, and those really matter!

Comment: the exact text was "justifications provided regarding purpose and conditions of your trip are not considered reliable"

Comment: @rex we have the answers for you already :)  Please look at the link Gagravarr provided and the especially this one:    http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten

Comment: i have checked the link . but , I seem to be clear on those areas .I am not able to zero in on the cause of refusal

Comment: impacts arising from history - none of us have ever breached laws or visa limits. credibility of evidence - son-in -law isnt a distant relative to sponsor .lack / poor quality evidence - all evidence is credible .parents-in-law are 70+ , they are bound to their country by their house , son ...forged documents - not applicable

Comment: @rex, time stamps show that it was a very quick check!  You did all that in 30 minutes?  Are you sure?  OK, but your next port of call is a lawyer with a practice area in Schengen.

Comment: In your first and second applications, did you mention that your parents will join you, or you just hid that fact? 
Note that even though the embassies are in different countries, they have a central system to track the applicants.

Comment: I did not see that link now . I had seen it sumtime last week . still , i felt i wanted a better picture for my specific case , that is why i posted my question today.hope this clarifies your point gayot

Comment: @ayesh ,i have put in all travellers details , i have added that they will be going to paris via kuwait so that we may join them on the same flight.in fact , i have even added our flight tickets and visas

Comment: @rex, I understand your wanting to frame your own case, but it's a duplicate anyway. You will have read that your refusal is a rather serious one and I doubt that changing consulates and throwing more evidence at them will be of much help.  You need to focus on what you have already provided.