# Visa refusal from Italy embassy dubai

Tags: visas

Sir today I received my passport from Italy embassy in dubai but my visa is refused how I don't know the reason, embassy respectable person mentioned my purpose and reason is not reliable I want and I have desire to see the European countries, its true I submitted all documents what the required so please tell me what I can do now plz 
Thanks 
From Ahmed

Comment: Please post the exact wording of the refusal, not a summary. The exact wording matters on these things!

Comment: Please see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten