# Required funds for American traveling to UK to visit fiancée

Tags: visas, uk, us-citizens, removal, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am looking to travel to the UK (Britain) to visit my fiancée. I have the passport and I am getting the funds for the visa and the trip. But I am not completely sure how much money I would need to actually be allowed in. I am looking to stay for about a month and a half to two months. I was already turned away at the door for not having enough funds with me, so I don't want to make that mistake again and waste another 1,800 for airfare only to get told I can't get in.

So please if someone could tell me at least the range of how much money I would need to get the Standard Visitors visa and to be able to get into the country. I will be staying with my fiancée the entire time, so I won't be needing funds for room and board and such.

What do I need to bring, both in documentation and in funds?

Comment: My understanding is that since you are applying for a visa rather than trying to enter visa-free (which is allowed for US citizens), the funds check will be done at the time of the visa application, and not at the border.  And you don't have to buy the plane ticket until after you have the visa.  So either way you won't waste the airfare.  Maybe someone can confirm this.

Comment: I also suggest you have a credit card. Frankly, it is rather unusual for US Citizens to be refused entry. Can you tell us more about the interview you had?

Comment: @NateEldredge, it's confirmed. And the best practices strategy following a removal is for the person to get an entry clearance, so the OP seems to be on the right track.

Comment: I'll look into getting a credit card, thank you. It was back in February, I was attempting to get in but no matter where I checked online it did not say that a visa was completely necessary so I didn't get one. To which I ended up being told once I got there that it was pretty necessary.. I dont know if the people that were there that day were just being harsh or what, but despite me having the money and a place to stay by their words "We cant let you stay because we are concerned for your safety" And didn't really tell me much else. Cause apparently I am not safe to stay with my fiancee

Comment: @Elizabeth Were you once refused entry to the UK at the border? Have you read our other questions about similar circumstances, as well as our *great many* questions about funds. (Quick hint - there is no fixed amount, there just has to be enough for what you plan to do, and enough that you aren't left destitute by the trip)

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/
http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42529/how-much-money-do-i-need-to-show-as-proof-of-support-when-applying-for-a-uk-stan
http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50059/will-us-boyfriend-have-issue-visiting-me-in-uk-for-3-months 
http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65219/refused-leave-to-enter-at-gatwick-airport-uk-and-subsequently-removed/
Please have a read of all of these, it may help you

Comment: Ohh, this one is good too: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69115/ive-been-granted-temporary-admission-to-the-uk-for-only-three-days-what-can-i
Also, remember that you are not allowed to get married in the UK on either visa-free entry or a visitor visa.

Comment: Alright, I am just going to say this. My fiancee doesn't even have a job herself. I am doing all of this, on my own because I desperately want to see her. So I am hardly this "Gold digging American" That some of you seem to think I am. I know I am not allowed to get married on the visitors visa sadly, if only I was. I will go through and read those @CMaster Thank you very much for the help. And yes I was refused at the border the first time

Comment: @Elizabeth those comments were unfortunate and it's sad for all of us when that happens. I hope it will not put you off the site.  Removals are always traumatic and you are totally right to want to do everything spit-spot correct the next time.  This question has been closed as a duplicate, next time try to make a unique question so we can get you the answers you need.  Chin up.