# Refusal of Schengen Visa from Spanish Embassy

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

Today, my visa application was refused from the Embassy of Spain, India. The reasons they mentioned are:

1. Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided.
2. You have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence, for the duration of the intended stay or for the return to the country of origin or residence, or for the transit to a third country into which you are certain to be admitted, or you are not in a position to acquire such means lawfully.
3. Your intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained.

My questions are:

- How can they say this while I have provided them with not only necessary financial documents, but also the letter of intent and return ticket of flight and proof of prepaid accommodations?
- Please tell me how much money they like to see in one's account before granting a visa?
- How can I overcome this sort of problems?

Comment: Partially answered in [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)

Comment: the third reason you list is icing on the cake drawn from other reasons. the second one is self explanatory. And the first one 'not provided' is the key.  There's an existing article about that, please read it and see how far you get.

Comment: Briefly, the concern is more likely to be about your income (Do you have a job? Provided evidence of a regular income?) than about cash available now.