# Do I have to supply a bank statement for my Schengen visa application if I have a sponsor?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, invitation-letters

Is it necessary to submit a bank statement which does not have enough funds,though I'm being supported by a friend in Germany when applying for a schengen visa to Germany from Zimbabwe?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The other question concerns an invitation only, with no implication of sponsorship or financial support.

Answer (score 4):

You have submitted a sponsored Schengen application to the German consulate in Zimbabwe.  Your sponsor has (presumably) submitted a "Verpflichtungserklärung" along with whatever else they thought necessary to establish their sponsorship capacity.  You have some bank statements of your own that show that you do NOT have the capacity to travel without a sponsor.

A useful rule coming from 'best practices' is that the applicant should bring everything relevant and provide as much assistance as possible to the official so that they can reach an informed and balanced decision. Anything at all is preferable to an evidential gap that leaves something up to the decision-makers imagination. Applicants often fall down on this point because they think that less transparency somehow works in their favour, but it doesn't; in fact it works against them. Using that as a guideline, let's look at your question...

> Is it necessary to submit a bank statement which does not have enough
>   funds,though I'm being supported by a friend in Germany when applying
>   for a schengen visa to Germany from Zimbabwe?

If you put this question to a lawyer, they would tell you: yes, bring them.

As soon as the decision-maker sees a "Verpflichtungserklärung" (or any other evidence of sponsorship) he will already assume that you are in reduced circumstances. And hence he will not expect a strong set of bank statements coming from you. That much is given.

But you can leverage your own statements to show that you are in a stable lifestyle and have on-going commitments to your homeland. Doing this is *absolutely fundamental* where sponsored applications are concerned and having a sponsor does not accomplish this. Failure on this point will invariably lead to refusal on...

> Your intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the
>   expiry of the visa applied for could not be ascertained.

Moreover, you can also leverage your own evidence to help show that you are being transparent and this goes a long way towards establishing that you are a bona fide visitor.  Transparency is decidedly preferable to non-transparency in these situations.  So bring a recent series of bank statements. If they are not asked for, you can even say, "*...I have additional evidence which is favourable to me and I would ask that you now examine it...*".

TIP: you can even annotate your bank statements to show specific instances that benefit your application. Lots of people don't think of this.  Pre-loading your evidence for success can pay off big-time.

Related: [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)

Related: [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)