# Schengen visit visa holder can directly travel from his/her origin home country to any schengen counrty?

Tags: visas, schengen

my query:Is this possible of legitimate that schengen visit visa holder can travel from his/her origin home country to any schengen country ... **for example: if i have schengen visit visa of Italy and i am traveling form my home country pakistan so can i go to sweden or spain rather italy directly from my home country??**

Comment: If the linked duplicate does not answer your question (for example if you have a single-entry visa), please reply to this comment and/or edit your question to explain why.

Comment: If you have a single-entry visa, you may only use it for the premise which you stated on the application. Minor changes to the route like a transfer via a different airport are acceptable, a complete change of the plans isn't.  You might not get caught if you never go to Italy on that visa, but if it gets noticed future applications will get **much** more difficult.

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten

Comment: thanks for the reply, it means i cant directly travel to any other desired destination, rather the destination which is stated in the application,

Comment: Thanks for the reply i appreciate that,,,,,But is this possible like , i have a visa of Italy but i want to go to spain first so can i buy the ticket to spain rather the destination who's visa on the passport ? it means i must have to enter the destination who's visa on the passport then i can go to any other schengen country like spain or sweden etc..! right ??  or if this is legitimate that i can go first to spain and then later few days after visit the Italy ..is this possible cause its a schengen visit visa not work permit ..!!