# German Visa Refused should I Appeal?

Tags: germany, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

The reason for Visa Refusal is that *the information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable*

I also emailed a consulate about it and their reply was as follows:

> Dear Sir / Madam,
>
> After a visa application is rejected, the applicant him-/herself can lodge an appeal against the Consulate´s decision. The appeal letter can be sent by original letter, by fax or as a scanned e-mail attachment. It has to contain the applicant's signature. It is also possible to authorize another person with the appeal process. This should also be done in writing. The letter should state the reasons why you want to appeal. If there are any more documents supporting the purpose of the applicant´s stay in Germany, you should also submit them and they will be taken into consideration by the officer. The appeal process might take a while, but you will usually get a response from the Consulate within 4-12 weeks' time. You also have the chance to re-apply. A special appointment for the submission of the new application cannot be granted.

I want to the appeal it what should I write and what all more documents need to Submit  it I am going there for sports purpose.

Comment: Please see [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten) for a comprehensive answer for this type of refusal.

Answer (score 3):

*The information [...] was not reliable* means that they are not sure you are a genuine tourist. They are afraid you want to work illegally and overstay. So you have to ask yourself, is it a deficiency in your submitted documents that led to the refusal, or are your current conditions such that you would want to stay in Germany *if you could*?

If you have very good reasons to return and they denied your application anyway, there may be something wrong with the documentation only.

- A stable, well-paid job to return to.
- Being halfway through university education, so you have to return for the exams.
- A history of travel to other European countries without overstay.

If that is not the case, an appeal probably won't help.