# How do I cancel an appeal for a refused Schengen visa with the German embassy in Karachi?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, pakistani-citizens, schengen-visas

My Schengen visa was refused by the German embassy in Karachi on the 11th of July, dated and received on the 14th of July, stating reason 8 that *“information submitted regarding purpose and conditions of stay was not reliable”*.

I submitted an appeal on the 25th of July but still have had no reply. Now I don't want to waste months waiting for decision.

- Is it possible to ask the embassy to cancel the appeal and reapply, and if so how do I go about it?
- Should I write an email to the embassy or should I go myself and talk to them?
- Or should I reapply to another Schengen state embassy in Karachi?

Comment: @GayotFow That seems to be a completely different question. This question asks how to cancel an appeal; the question you link asks what "information... not reliable" means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to ask the embassy to cancel the appeal and reapply, and if so how do I go about it?

To withdraw an appeal so you can clear the way for a fresh application, you should write a letter stating your intent to withdraw the appeal, including as much information as you can regarding the original application, the original appeal letter and any correspondence you have received from the issuing body in the intervening time.

This allows the issuing body to match your correspondence more easily.

You should receive notification that your appeal has been withdrawn - at this point you can go ahead with a fresh application.

> Or should I reapply to another Schengen state embassy in Karachi?

Only if your travel plans allow this - you should always be applying for a visa to the Schengen member state which covers the most significant portion of your visit, or the member state of entry if all portions are equally significant.

Schengen member states frown on visa shopping, so simply applying to another member state may get you into trouble at some point during your trip.