# Why was I asked to provide proof of travel AFTER returning from Schengen area?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, austria

I have received my Schengen visa (short-stay) issued by the Austrian Embassy in Australia (main purpose Germany)

I have been told that *'upon return, you are expected to show proof to the Austrian Embassy that you have travelled as stated in your application and in your itinerary. Please therefore provide for example the invoices issued from your hotels, your train/bus transport receipts, stamps in your passport etc.'*

Is this a regular request? Was I singled out and should I be concerned? Also, does this mean that I cannot make *any* change to my travel plans? (e.g. - depart a country on the 3rd instead of the 4th or stay in a different hotel?). What would happen if they are not happy with the proof?

Comment: After your return because they will use it for your _next_ visa application.

Comment: @chirlu Yes I understand that though I could not find any instance on the Internet of this being a requested which is why I am a bit worried as to whether they possibly singled me out.

Comment: Just a wild guess, by it might be related to getting an Austrian via for a trip to Germany.

Comment: I can't find the question, but I know we've seen this at least once on travel.stackexchange before. Some consulates seem to use it as a quality control measure, and to ensure visas aren't issued in the future to those who have overstayed.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo perhaps Austria represents Germany in the applicant's place of residence.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The missions for Germany and Latvia are represented by the Embassy of Austria in Australia [link](http://www.vfsglobal.com/austria/australia/)

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Here's another page from the German embassy confirming that: http://www.australien.diplo.de/Vertretung/australien/en/03/Visa/Visa.html: "The Austrian Embassy in Canberra is responsible for issuing Schengen Visas on behalf of Germany in all States and Territories of Australia."  Countries can enter into these arrangements even when they both have representation in the foreign territory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this a regular request?

If by regular you mean it happens often or routinely, no; this type of notice has not been widely seen previously.

> Was I singled out

It is unlikely that you were singled out because the quote you gave has the appearance of a standarized text. It is more likely that you are in the vanguard of a new policy advising all individuals fitting a given profile that they may be called upon to provide additional evidence. Note the verbiage: "you are expected" as opposed to "you are required".

> and should I be concerned?

No, not at all. It's reasonable, and they are not asking for anything a diligent traveler would not have at hand at the end of trip.

Moreover, this provides you with a great (and early) opportunity to establish your bona fides for your next visa application. They love to see a performance history and, heretofore, there has been no way to provide evidence in a conclusive manner. You can view this as a favourable step!

> Also, does this mean that I cannot make any change to my travel plans? (e.g. - depart a country on the 3rd instead of the 4th or stay in a different hotel?).

People make minor adjustments to their plans all the time, and they have always been happy to accommodate it. What they will be after (in all likelihood) are cases where an individual has made radical changes to their itinerary without being able to explain them. As long as your changes are tenable and the overall purpose of your visit is maintained you can expect them to take a reasonable approach.

> What would happen if they are not happy with the proof?

If your plans changed during the course of your visit, you can explain. If your explanation is reasonable, they will no doubt be happy with it. If, however, they conclude that your application was specious in some way, then see [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)

Comment: A change in itinerary could change which country should have processed the visa. That sort of change may invite extra scrutiny.

Answer (score -1):

> Is this a regular request? Was I singled out and should I be concerned?

I don't think you should be concerned. I'm not sure if it's regular or not, but it has been reported on various travelling forums in Vietnam that the French embassy and consulate in Vietnam often randomly choose people who must report to them after the trip to make sure that they follow the plan. That usually applies to people who go backpacking and apply for a free-trip visa without an invitation letter.

However I've also seen travel agencies claiming that the embassy/consulate requires them to show passports of all the people joining the tour after the trip, therefore you have to leave your passports at their place for a few more days

> Also, does this mean that I cannot make any change to my travel plans? (e.g. - depart a country on the 3rd instead of the 4th or stay in a different hotel?).

It doesn't mean that you can't make any changes, but you'll have less flexibility.

For example a person I know bought a temporary flight ticket to apply for a visa. Then she realized that there were other much cheaper flight choices and intended to modify the plan after obtaining the visa. Unfortunately she must report to the consulate 2 days after the trip, thus can't change the plan anymore and had to continue with the expensive tickets