# Is it an issue if my name appears differently on my documents and passport?

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas

My name on my national ID card and education documents is only my first name. My passport has both first name and last name in respective fields. My school admission letter has my complete name, Abdul Basit Hafeez.

ID: Abdul Basit (First Name)
Educational Documents: Abdul Basit (First Name)
Admission Letter: Abdul Basit Hafeez
Passport: Lastname= Hafeez, FirstName = Abdul Basit

Can my French long stay student visa be rejected because of this?

Last year, my visa was rejected with this statement:

> The information provided to justify the conditions of the stay is incomplete and/or unreliable.

Comment: It is possible that the difference in names is the reason you were rejected. Is it normal to have a difference between school records and ID card in your country? Is it possible to get school records reissued with your full name?

Comment: @user1659 thanks for comment, no that isnt common. and i have same name(first name) on ID and education documents, its not possible to change school certificate now

Comment: As it was not an issue for admittance to the school, it suggests that either the premise (study) or other arrangements (funds, tuition, accommodation) may not have been satisfied or well-documented.

Comment: @Giorgio If the uni has accepted the student, surely that automatically satisfies the premise? I agree the other issues are still open questions.

Comment: You may be interested to read: [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/53411/3221)

Comment: @A.B. Can you get your National ID card changed to show your full name (I’d have thought this would be obligatory anyway?) and ask the school to certify a copy of your passport or provide some other form of confirmation that Abdul Basit and Abdul Basit Hafeez are one and the same person?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify questions/comments. Putting on hold for now.