# Should I apply again for a UK visa?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

Last year in July, I applied for a UK visitor visa along with my wife, which were not approved.

I am the sole proprietor of my company, so I presented only my business bank statement. I never used my personal bank account due to fully signatory of my business accounts.

I couldn't demonstrate my circumstances.

After that, I opened my personal bank account and deposited an amount every month for my personal living expenses. We went to other countries for sightseeing after that refusal.

In October, I applied for a business visa at the German embassy to attend an exhibition to buy goods for my company but that was also refused and they told me your stay and purpose of visit is not reliable. I didn't tell them about my UK refusal because they didn't ask me. Maybe they knew it and this refusal was due to the UK refusal.

Now my question is:

My personal bank statement has been stable for the last nine to ten months. May I apply again for a UK visitor visa? Because I want to go other countries for business and leisure trips, but every country will refuse me due to the UK refusal. May I first clear the UK objection?

Answer (score 3):

It’s a mistake to focus solely on bank statements, other aspects of an application such as ties to your home country are equally important. There is an excellent answer here explaining a Schengen refusal for the reason you were given: [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten) and a detailed answer on typical reasons for a UK refusal [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) You are free to apply for a UK visa again, however you will have to disclose both refusals which is likely to significantly reduce your chances of success.