# Greece visa rejection

Tags: visas, schengen, greece

Me and my husband applied for Greece visa 15 days ago, and we got rejected.

Reason:

1. The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.
2. Your intention to leave the territory of the member states before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained.

We got Schengen visa in the past, and UK visa as well.

What should we do?

And if we want to reapply for visa, should we apply at the Greek embassy or another embassy in the Schengen catagory?

Answer (score 2):

If Greece is the main destination of your trip, you should apply to the Greek authorities. Applying to other countries might raise suspicions that you're just trying to find someone who will give you a visa, and that might make it harder to get one.

Things have changed in the world (and possibly in your life too) so just because you got a visa before doesn't mean you can get one now.

As (almost) always when a visa was refused you should address the concerns raised in the refusal, more information can be found in other questions, notably:

[Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten?rq=1)