# Is a travel loan considered as funds parking for a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am an Indian citizen planning for a trip to Europe from India. I plan to take a loan for the trip.

A visa agent informed me that travel loans will result in rejection of the visa application while another agent said that it's OK to take a loan for travel.

Can someone clarify this for me please?

Comment: I think the point is whether you can afford the trip. If you have to take a loan out to finance it, you may give the impression that you can’t. Hiowever, whether it would harm your chances of approval depends on the rest of your personal circumstances eg savings, travel history, job/income, ties to home etc.

Comment: With the visa application, you have to show that your financial situation allows you to pay for the trip. If you need a loan to do so, you have obviously shown that you are not really able to afford the trip. I do not know how visa officers consider this, but I think common sense would be to decide that you are not eligible for a visa if you need a loan to be able to travel.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your views. Are there any official contact details for Schengen Visa application office/centre etc. where I can clarify this with an official?

Comment: The consulate officials will not discuss it with you. They will simply refuse your visa and state that the justification for the purpose and conditions was not reliable.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I would think that if you were approved for a loan, then you *can* afford it, because you now have the money, from the loan. Why would the consulate care how you plan to pay it off afterwards? As long as you have the money during the trip and then you go back home, whatever happens after that is not their problem.

Answer (score 7):

There are specific standard refusal reasons which fit this situation:

> You have not provided proof of sufficient means of subsistence, for the duration of the intended stay or for the return to the country of origin or residence, or for the transit to a third country into which you are certain to be admitted, or you are not in a position to acquire such means lawfully.

And

> The information submitted regarding justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.

The first reason means that you must show you have enough money to afford all of the expenses of your trip: plane tickets, hotel, food, etc. and that you must have obtained this money through legal means.

The second reason is more complex. It means in general that the overall application must make sense and the documents submitted must be genuine and related to the declared purpose of the visit. (We have a lengthy explanation of [what to do about this refusal reason](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/53411/3221).)

If you have to take a loan to afford the trip, then the consular officer will be inclined to believe that you cannot truly afford the visit on your own. He or she may think that you instead plan to come to Europe to live and work illegally. Whether you actually intend that or not, the officer will still refuse the visa.

It is best to pay for such a visit from your own personal savings, and to have personal circumstances which permit you to save enough money on your own to afford such a visit. It is possible for a family member or very close friend to sponsor you and provide the money for your trip, but the reason for that person to pay for your expenses must be carefully justified in the visa application.