# Documents required for sponsoring girlfriend for Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, spain

My girlfriend and I are traveling to Spain next year, and wanted to know what all documents would be required?

I have my own business and she is studying, by the time we will go, she would have completed her studies.

I am sponsoring the trip.

PS: If I show that she works for me, can I give her the leaving certificate for the trip? Will that create complication?

PS: Applying from India.

Comment: Does/will she genuinely be working for you? Just an opinion, but if eg she has worked for you for several months when she applies, and has the paperwork to prove it (employment contract, payslips, tax returns, bank statements), then maybe it’d be ok. If she has just started, then personally I think it could cause suspicion. If she has a strong travel history already, then maybe not so much of a concern.

Answer (score 4):

You have to understand the meaning of "sponsorship" for a Schengen visa.

- You will not be believed if **you** try to promise that **she** will leave the Schengen area again. Once she is in, **you** cannot make her leave.
- You will not be believed if **you** try to promise that **she** is a law-abiding citizen who would not overstay. Once she is in, **you** cannot make her leave.

What "sponsorship" means is an explanation of her source of funds. Nothing more, nothing less.

- Some people borrow money to immigrate into the EU, with the plan to overstay, work, and repay the debt. You must explain **why you would give her the money as a gift**, with no expectation of repayment. That means explaining your relationship.
- Some people spend all their money to get themselves or a relative into the EU, with the plan to overstay, work, and send money home. You must explain why **you would spend the money on a luxury** like tourism. That means explaining your income and expenditure, and also hers. Legal, documented income in excess of reasonable living expenses are more important than lots of money simply sitting in your account.

Only say that she is working for you if that is the truth. **Everything has to fit together.** If she is working in your company, does she have a payslip, a bank account with regular deposits, the usual taxes? How does that fit with the completion of her studies?

Lies will only make everything more complicated. What you need is a simple, reasonable explanation. You are a couple. You earn enough to afford the trip for both of you, and the relationship explains why you share your money. It is perfectly normal that not every couple is married. It is perfectly normal that one partner earns more than the other.

Comment: Good answer (+1), but I'm concerned the first two "you can" bullet points might be misunderstood if read carelessly. They're really "you _can't_ (usefully)" points. What would you say to toning them down to "you might" or even "you might try"?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, edited.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t say where you’ll be applying from, it would be a good idea to check the website of the Consulate of Spain in your location before applying.

Using the list of required documents for a Schengen and Tourist visa published by the Spanish Consulate in London as a guide, you’ll need (as a minimum):

- Passport or travel document valid for at least 3 months beyond the intended departure from the Schengen area with at least two blank pages to affix the visa.
- Travel Medical Insurance for the entire period of the intended stay.The minimum coverage must be €30.000.
- Confirmation of employment status
- Last 3 months bank statements showing that you have sufficient means of subsistence. Your girlfriend should submit her own statements, even if you are paying for the trip.
- Proof of confirmed and paid return ticket and accommodation

The exact documents you’ll need depends on your circumstances.

Source: http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/LONDRES/en/Consulado/Pages/DocumentsRequired.aspx

Comment: Applying from India.

We are planning to keep about 4000eur worth in INR, in each of our accounts for the trip, for 4-5months prior to applying, the only problem is reason of return.

Comment: @Harsh There are lots of questions about Schengen refusals on TSE. Reading this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten may help your understanding. If you yourself think reason to return is a problem, you can bet the Consulate will too. Perhaps consider going elsewhere and building up a travel history before applying to Schengen (or other comparable destinations with equally stringent requirements, such as USA, Canada, UK, Australia).

Comment: She lived in USA for 10yrs, dubai for 1yr....however this was back wen she was young, like uptil the age of 10