# German Visa application rejected

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

I am a student studying in Dubai (my family is also staying here, my dad works here), and recently a company in Munich, Germany took interest in me and invited me for an on site face-to-face interview. So, I applied for a Short Visit visa for Germany, here in Dubai.
I had every single document they were asking for attached, including my fathers bank statement (since I'm a student here) but it came out rejected.
They're asking for my financial ties here, but I literally have no ties financially since I'm a student!
What should I do? Is there no other choice?

[image]
[image]

Edit:   @phoog I have attached the following 1-Application form 2-Passport copy, my fathers passport copy, both of our Emirates ID Card copy and also our driving license card copy.3- Two Passport sized pictures. 4-Travel Insurance. 5-Flight reservation copy. 6-Hotel Reservation copy. 7-Letter from my college stating they do not mind. 8-My fathers last four months bank statement. 9-Invitation letter from the company i was invited for the interview. 10-No objection letter from my father.11-A cover letter made by me. 12-Travel Itinerary 13- My birth certificate copy. 14-my school certificate stating that i've been staying here for 10 years+

Comment: If you have no financial ties, you should check other ties then can demonstrate that you will leave Germany. Note: If your father is paying for you (travel and to live in UAE), that is the financial tie. What are your study program? Looking for a job in Germany when studying may not seem appropriate (but if you are at end of study).

Comment: Does your father have a Business or something there? I should think you would be needing an affidavit and a business name of some sort. So i would advise when next you apply, come with an affidavit and your father's business name. Since its your parents sponsoring you, affidavit of sponsorship can also come a long way. #Mythoughts

Comment: *Your intent of leaving the Schengen zone wasn't recognizeable.* – Most likely you are simply applying for the wrong type of visa. Job seeking with a tourist visa is not permitted.

Comment: They don’t doubt your sponsor but they do think there’s a risk you’ll abandon your studies in Dubai to stay in Germany. Since your father supports you in Dubai he could presumably continue to do so at a distance. If your only tie to Dubai is completing your studies and they’ve already seen proof of that, I doubt there’s much that will satisfy them. Can you ask your prospective employer to interview you via eg Skype?

Comment: Some questions i'm going to answer now, 1- I've already stated to them that i'm a student in the cover letter and that i have no financial ties here myself but my fathers.2- I have not completed my education here, and i have given them proof saying that i will come back for my further examinations here. 3- My father doesn't have any business here. 4-I've e-mailed the consulate if i could go to germany for an interview, they said i can and they i could go on a tourism visa.5-I guess the last option is my only choice. I'll ask them if they can take the interview online....  This is just sad.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I did offer them my fathers bank statement, it didn't work.. I'm studying Aircraft Engineering btw, I have finished my basic courses, but i'm still attending the advance exams. Which is not a problem because i'm doing it with KLM Dutch airlines, and they have an examination center in Germany as well.

Comment: You should carefully read this closely related information: [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/53411/3221)

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you for the information share. Unfortunately, All my documentation work is proper and doesn't correlate with any of the ones in that post.

Answer (score 6):

***Update:***

So guys, i E-mailed the consulate stating that I'm a student and i have no financial ties and i've submitted my father's bank statement. And i told them that i won't and cannot stay in Germany illegally because i have examinations to attend in Dubai (and provided proof of that). After having no replies for 2 days, all of a sudden, i get an e-mail saying that "the consulate officer has come to a positive conclusion after re-assessing my application, You can come and drop off your passport at our Drop box at Jumeirah 1 (Their location), and then you can pick it up after 2 working days from our collection counter"

Thanks for all your help guys!