# Flight Ticket booked , But Visa Rejected for second time for the Country France

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals, france, serial-refusals

I have booked the flight ticket , but France VISA is Rejected for the Second time , i am Cluelesss

i have Booked the Cheaper flight tickets , which i was not aware of was it was NON-REFUNDABLE , and the VISA is been Rejected saying 'the Intentdent Stay was not Reliable '

My purpose of visit is specified properly as Honeymoon trip. I have given itinerary for the entire trip along with necessary accommodation and internal schengen travelling arrangements, i have provided Sponsorship letter from my parents along with bank statements and their passports. I am a Software Engineer, working at Banglore. I have submitted my Employee details from my office. Even the travel insurance and NOC from my wife's parents. All the documents specified in the list were presented. After my first rejection, i waited till my marriage completion and immediately after marriage i applied for marriage certificate and presented it for the reapplication of Visa. Even though i strived hard for getting all the documents ready both mine and my wife's Visa has been rejected. Visiting Europe countries is a dream for majority of people and i am one among them, especially the Eiffel tower in Paris being one among the Wonders of World also the Switzerland which is the top Honeymoon destination, one of the beautiful dream to be fulfilled, hence i have been struggling by applying for Visa, the second time but it has been rejected now, i am not able to understand the reason for  disapproval. 
Please let me know if I have to submit any other documents that will help me get the visa , I will be happy to provide them immediately. I am ready to give confirmed receipt for booking and also any other document which they ask for.

I have paid 240+ Euros VFS charges for the visa i.e Rs.30,000 and visiting the VFS Global Office 4th time. Also most importantly I have already booked the flight and paid for my flight tickets which is around Rs.90,000
With lot of effort I have afforded this money and I hope France embassy understands and reconsiders our application to facilitate the visa process. I kindly request you understand my concern. Let me know the proper reason and the requirement of necessary document which i need to submit for my Visa Approval.
I hardly have 10 days left from today for my flight which is booked on 28-11-2019(BLR-MCT-CDG with eTicket receipt:9102116368731,68732)with the return date being 13-12-2019.

My flight ticket is booked and that booked ticket is non-refundable , please consider my application (Please Find the attachments )the E-copy of the ticket is also attached in the mail

Hence please consider my urge and i request you kindly help me to facilitate the process as soon as possible.

Comment: Not the advice you want to hear but please stop and not waste more moneys. Try some other destinations. After 2 denials This is not going to be an easy case without more and more costs.

Comment: Do you have a prior travel history? Did anything else change in your circumstances since the previous refusal apart from getting married? Possible duplicate of [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)

Comment: Even if your parents are providing money for the trip, France wants to see that you have solid finances--a lot of savings and that you're not using them all to pay for the trip.

Comment: We cannot consider your application here (that's not what this website is for). Your visa was denied, you need to step back and re-evaluate what you are saying in your application. To me it seems that you tried to applied, got denied, then got married and tried again using "honeymoon" as the reason. What was the reason for your first application?