# Remonstration Procedure for German Visa in Karachi

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas, pakistan, german-language

I apply for visa to visit airshow in Berlin , I am an airline professional, I submitted invitation from sponsor and airshow ticket and all required documents as property owned my me and marriage certificate. Recently my visa was rejected for following reasons, 
The information provided on the purpose and condition of intended stay was not credible
Your intention to leave the territory of member states before expirey

Noe I want to apply for remonstration , can someone guide me how to make remonstration email and where to send remonstration email in Karachi, Pakistan.

Comment: The appeals process is included in the refusal notice. See section 12.3 https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf#page78 Is there something specific about the appeals process described in the refusal you received that you don’t understand?

Comment: You can apply for a remonstrance if you wish, and it might be successful, but you will probably need to [fix the problems with your application](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/53411/3221) and reapply. Even if you have had many Schengen visas before, every application must be prepared carefully as they are each judged on their own merits.