# Recent graduate planning to attend a conference in Paris: Will my visa application be rejected?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, applications, paris, proof-of-ties

I have received an invitation to attend a conference in Paris for a week. However, I am a recent graduate and I am currently preparing for the [GATE exams](https://gate.iitk.ac.in/). I am in a dilemma as to whether my visa application will be rejected due to the fact that I am unemployed and do not have sufficient documents to prove my ties to my home country.

Will attaching my registration details for the exams and mentioning my future plans of pursuing higher studies in my home country be of any help?

Comment: Do you have any previous travel history to Schengen or an equivalent jurisdiction? Are you presenting / speaking at the conference (a more compelling reason for the trip than simoly attending it). IMHO if you yourself have significant doubts about the strength of your application, then you should not risk a refusal

Comment: No probably this would be my first international trip. These are my doubts as a result of my research regarding schengen visa. I'm a prospective student who is yet to enroll in an institution. Based on my readings you stand a better chance if you are employed or are currently a student enrolled in an institution in your home country. And regarding the conference, yes I would be presenting a talk there.

Comment: With no prior travel history you’re highly likely to get refused unless the rest of your application is 100% watertight (which by your own admission it would not be). Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten

Comment: Update : I got the visa ! If anyone is in the same boat as I was, prepare a a good cover letter describing the purpose of your visit and double check your paperwork. If you have compelling reason for you visit then ig embassy mostly give you visa, It worked in my case, so may or may not work in every case :)