# Help regarding rejection of Slovenian (Schengen) Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals, slovenia

I recently applied for a Schengen Tourist Visa through Slovenia via India as my maximum number of stays are in Slovenia only. I made sure that ALL my documents are genuine and fine and still it got rejected. I have a job here btw.

Reasons for rejection are as follows:

1."The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable."

2."There are reasonable doubts as to the reliability, as to the authenticity of the supporting documents submitted or as to veracity of their contents."

I do understand that these reasons are highly vague and anything could have gotten wrong, but has anyone else faced this issue and got it resolved somehow?

Comment: Impossible to answer without details. But then, you shouldn't give too many personal details on the web for safety reasons. There are people who got it resolved. There are others who did not get it resolved.

Comment: Just speculating: Might be a problem with your hotel bookings or tour operator or something similar inside Slovenia. At least that would be an area where they might be more aware of problems than you are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schengen Visa Refusal: Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten)

Comment: While the refusal wording appears vague to you, the words used in Schengen visa application refusals actually do have specific meanings and inferences. Read the extensive question and answers and comments contained in the previous comment cited by @mlc. That previous question contains significant information that can help you understand why your application was refused, and what changes might improve it.

Comment: I appreciate all of your comments, but even though the first reason is common with what @mlc has shared, the second reason is different since they do no have doubts regarding me leaving the Schengen Area or not.

Comment: @Jan, thanks for your comment, I have made the bookings through Booking.com and have paid the full price wherever possible, although some of the stays are fully refundable on cancellation. Do you reckon that might be something that is going wrong?

Comment: It could be that Slovenia has tightened its immigration risk appetite https://bnn.network/world/slovenia/slovenia-faces-sharp-rise-in-irregular-migration/

Comment: "reasonable doubts as to the reliability, as to the authenticity of the supporting documents submitted or as to veracity of their contents": you're going to have to figure out what gave them reason to doubt your documents.  It could be anything, really, and it might not seem all that reasonable to you.  It's a difficult position to be in.

Comment: Have you had Schengen visa(s) previously? What was your full intended itinerary, and the reason for choosing Slovenia as your main destination?

Comment: I wonder how one would prove (beyond reasonable doubt) that a booking.com booking is genuine? Does one need to get a paper with a stamp from the hotel?

Comment: I agree with @phoog that visa rejections are kind of arbitrary. Among friends and family, we have had some really stupid rejections. We are always relieved if someone actually gets a visa.

Comment: @Traveller the obvious explanation for the increase seems to have eluded the author of that article, namely that Croatia joined the Schengen area, so Slovenia no longer has a land border with any non-Schengen country.  Slovenia tightening up their visa processing isn't going to have much of an effect there.

Comment: @Traveller, my reason was tourism and sightseeing and I did give them a day to day itinerary with hotel names. Although I must confess that some elements of my itinerary were very casual like "Explore local town of foot" while not giving proper clarification of what it might mean.

Comment: @HarshilRustagi In which case perhaps they suspected you engineered an itinerary so that you could apply to Slovenia instead of a more sought-after option. Which might also explain refusal reason #2. Slovenia isn’t an obvious destination for tourists from India https://www.statista.com/statistics/1060995/slovenia-tourist-arrivals-by-source-country/

Comment: Hello guys, just got a major information that I need to share with you all. So Slovenia needs all the accomodations booked directly through the hotel or through a travel agent in India or Slovenia for the first time travellers and this could be the reason for my rejection. I checked the VFS website once again with full focus.