Berlin tourist visa refused, should appeal or file a remonstrance
I applied for schengen (German tourist visa) but was refused a Schengen tourist visa based on the following two reasons

The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable
The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.
There are reasonable doubts as to the reliability, as to the authenticity of the supporting documents submitted or as to the veracity of their contents.

What does all this means and solutions please?
Refusal received on: 10/09/2024 Travel date: 10/22/2024
All my documents but itinerary are confirmed except the hotel booking because I opted for “pay on property“

Could the hotel booking be the problem?
Do I file a remonstrance or appeal?
Do I change to other Schengen countries as I really want to take a vacation outside USA with my two weeks leaves at work especially to see all those tourists exotic places I watched in movies and equally give myself a therapy session after divorce.


Other Schengen countries will probably know about the refusal. It would be better to post a copy of the refusal letter here (with personal details redacted). Note that filing a "remonstrance" isn't good. Vast numbers of visa applications are refused for reasons given.

This question is similar to: German Visa Refused should I Appeal?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Another question with relevant information is here.

What is your citizenship? And immigration status in US if not a citizen?

A Citizen of Nigeria and  US green card holder

You might also gain valuable knowledge by reading: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53411/schengen-visa-refusal-justification-for-the-purpose-and-conditions-of-the-inten

The reasons given does not suggest it's the hotel booking that is the problem, Why do you choose to ignore the reasons given and try to find another problem - I can't think of a case where that is the way to deal with it.

Check their last point. It say that they think that some documents are not genuine (or tampered). And they have a lot of experience on evaluating documents. Give your application to a friend to check it, and get feedback.

I doubt that US permanent residents are routinely refused a Schengen visa. The 3rd refusal reason is pretty serious, if you really believe you have grounds to appeal you should probably get advice from an Immigration lawyer. Related question Consular fraud penalties for Schengen

Last point might also mean that some document is genuine, but contains some (seriously) false information. E.g. genuine passport with false date of birth.
