# My visa has been denied twice and im applying for a new one in about 2 weeks

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, tunisian-citizens

I'm a tunisian citizen, I'm 21 years old and I'm a student. I do not have a job - in my country you get one at age around 24 after finishing your studies. But I do have a source of money.

I am going to apply for a German short visa to visit my girlfriend. We've been together for about 5 years now but we never met because of her parents they would like to see me first.  That's why I'm applying for visa. I have no intention to stay in Germany or get a job there.

I would like just to spend a week with her to meet her and her parents. I had a tumor before but I do thank god i survived from it and she was the only person that helped me going through it. So my question is if there is a way to help me get their trust. Again I'm not a criminal I would never do something illegal or get her in trouble.

Comment: We don't know why the visa application was denied. Posting a copy of the refusal letter (with personal information blacked out) might help generate useful answers.

Comment: No sir, I did not apply yet but i will in about a week

Comment: David, they said the reason wasnt clear or convincing but i did say the truth

Comment: How long does your course of studies have left?

Comment: You probably can call me the luckiest guy or the opposite, like i mentioned that i had a tumor and i was trying to survive and with that i had to waste some years old study so im a bit behind. my plan is to finish university but i still have years left. i know im not luckiest guy out there

Comment: ^^ I think that's the right question. @PacmanDD Could we have the _exact_ wording of the refusal? "The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable" is potentially more serious.  Our question [Understanding the reasons for a Schengen visa refusal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/31520/11491) might also be useful.

Comment: After declining my visa they give u a paper which tells u why they refused. it is in german
there is 9 options and i passed them all except the last one which says

Ihre Absicht, Vor Ablauf des Visums Aus Dem Hoheitsgebiet der Mitliedstaaten AusZureisen, Konnte nicht festgestellt werden
which means in google 


Their intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the visa expired could not be established

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, you fit almost exactly the pattern of people that German immigration will be concerned about. You have no job; you have a relationship which is purely long distance; you seem to have few ties to your home country; you come from a country that many people try to leave and migrate to Europe. You look to them very like the kind of person who will come to Germany and then fail to leave. It unfortunately doesn't matter whether you are that kind of person, if you look like that kind of person they will deny you a visa. Simply promising to abide by the rules will not affect your application.

The most problematic item is your relationship. A five year relationship where you have never met the other person is unusual, especially if you were both sixteen when it started. Regardless of whether it is a genuine relationship, it sounds fake to the immigration officials, and that will likely cause them to refuse you a visa.

Your best immediate way of solving this problem is to abandon your plans to come to Germany, and instead meet with your girlfriend and/or her parents in Tunisia. German citizens will have no problem visiting Tunisia, and this will let your girlfriend and her parents see you in your home, and meet some of your family also. Doing this not only removes the need for you to travel to Germany, but also adds credibility to your relationship with your girlfriend, which will help future applications. Meeting her in some other country, such as Turkey, would work as well.

Continuing to apply after having been turned down, without a significant change in your circumstances, is only going to make matters worse for you. You need to do something to demonstrate that your relationship is genuine and that you have ties to your home country.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your answer but her parents wont let her visit any other country unless they meet me thats why i have to go to germany, Is there another way to prove my chances?

Comment: How old is your girlfriend? If she is over eighteen then her parents cannot stop her visiting Tunisia. If she is under eighteen then you have other problems.

Comment: Isn't your girlfriend old enough that she can go to Tunesia without her parents consent?. If you meet her a couple of times, the relationship will look a lot less suspicious to the german authorities.

Comment: Yes shes  21 years old like me but her parents wont let her go to tunisia, they're scared and i understand. people think tunisia isnt safe but it is as safe as germany

Comment: Once again, your girlfriend's parents cannot prevent her visiting Tunisia. If she is telling you "my parents won't let me go" then you might want to consider the possibility that she actually doesn't want to visit you, but doesn't want to tell you.

Comment: No no i know her and i know her parents she would never think like that.. again heres what they paper said
fter declining my visa they give u a paper which tells u why they refused. it is in german there is 9 options and i passed them all except the last one which says Ihre Absicht, Vor Ablauf des Visums Aus Dem Hoheitsgebiet der Mitliedstaaten AusZureisen, Konnte nicht festgestellt werden which means in google Their intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the visa expired could not be established –

Comment: You have never met her or her parents. But that's none of my business. The point is you have essentially no chance of getting a visa based on your current situation.

Comment: Thank you for your time so there is no way to improve my chances?

Comment: The best way to improve your chances is to convince your girlfriend to meet you in Tunesia.

Comment: What if we meet somewhere else like in turkey or something would that also improve my chances?

Comment: Yes, but we're probably talking about increasing your chance of getting a Schengen visa from zero to low. You should also look at the other things @DJClayworth wrote in the last sentence: improve your ties to your home country.

Comment: @DJClayworth Sure, the parents can't (legally) prevent their adult daughter from travelling wherever she wants. However, in purely practical terms, refusing to take their wishes into account could cause huge problems for her in her life. Especially if she's currently living with them and/or needs them to help pay for her trip.

Comment: This is pretty "unfair" if i might say like i say i can only get a good job unless i finish my studies and thats around 2-3 years like i said im a bit behind because i was sick. tunisia is really hard to get a job so basicailly im screwed right?

Comment: Unfortunately, as @DJClayworth stated in his answer...your chances of getting a visa right now are practically 0 given your current status. Your personal situation would have to change (finish our studies, full time job, etc.) in order for you to get that visa.

Comment: Ask the parents of the girl to visit a country you can travel to without visa troubles and meet them there. Turkey is a good one for people from Germany as there are many relatively cheap flights.

Comment: @Pacman DD If you’ve never met her parents you don’t ‘know them’, and some people would say you don’t ‘know’ your girlfriend either (or even have a girlfriend) if you’ve never met in person, despite a history going back 5 years. The advice to ask your online friend and her parents to meet you in a neutral country that’s easy for everyone to get to is good advice. If she still says no, it’s not possible, then best re-think the ‘relationship’. If she says yes, good luck, I hope it works out for you.